# Unable to access jar when running gradle dropwizard app deployed on heroku

Tags: heroku, dropwizard

I am trying to deploy a dropwizard app on heroku which fails to launch.
Its works fine locally using "gradle run server config.yml"

I am using gradle for build and when I push to heroku the **build is successful.**
My gradle stage task dependsOn clean and jar(fat jar creation)

My **Procfile** has:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar dropwizard-app/build/libs/dropwizard-app.jar server dropwizard-app/config.yml

**The above fails with "Unable to access jarfile dropwizard-app/build/libs/dropwizard-app.jar"**

I have tried unsuccessfully with

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar build/libs/dropwizard-app.jar server config.yml

I have also tried to execute using gradle command

> web: gradle run server config.yml

This gives an error 
**bash: gradle command not found**

My gradle tasks are as follows:

```
    task stage(dependsOn: ['clean', 'jar'])

    run {
        args 'server', 'config.yml'
    }

    jar {
        manifest {
            attributes  'Title': 'dropwizard-app', 'Version': version,'Main-Class':  mainClassName
        }
        archiveName 'dropwizard-app'
        dependsOn configurations.runtime
        from {
            configurations.compile.collect {it.isDirectory()? it: zipTree(it)}
        }
    }
```

Am I missing out something here?
How do I launch my dropwizard application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Got it working.

As mentioned above I was trying to execute dropwizard-app.jar
but the jar created on heroku was not of mentioned name, it took the default archive name
starting with *build-'some autogenerated value'.jar*

So I added a **settings.gradle** to my project:

```
 rootProject.name = 'dropwizard-app'
```

Now the jar created was dropwizard-app-1.0.jar

as I have set the version attribute to 1.0 in build.gradle

I used `heroku run bash`
to check the files on heroku

Comment: +1. Heroku tries to be cute with fancy APIs and big buttons to press without real juice. It is not mentioned in any of their documentation that the uploaded artifact is renamed. At least not that I could find with an hour of googling.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Maven-based deployment guide describing [how to deploy a Dropwizard to Heroku](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/09/how-to-deploy-a-dropwizard-project-to-heroku/) which may offer some help. While it doesn't cover gradle, it does point out some common gotchas with the Heroku environment.

For example, your Procfile should look like this:

```
web java $JAVA_OPTS -Ddw.http.port=$PORT -Ddw.http.adminPort=$PORT -jar path/to/dw/module/target/example-develop-SNAPSHOT.jar server path/to/dw/module/config-heroku.yml
```